# Windows server 2012 R2: Adding support on new cipher

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

### Environment Description

I have a VM (hosted in Azure) cluster (one of many identical machines) that I'm using for running my application. I have noticed that some webpages are cannot be loaded in those machines. Why? SSL\TLS issues.

Problematic page example: [here](https://royal-babynews.com).

When I'm entered this URL with IE11 in my VM- I'm getting back "This page cannot be displayed" message.

[image]

When I'm entered this URL with FireFox in same machine - it's working smoothly! (so it's not a network problem).

### The problem:

I discovered that the problem is **Elliptic Curve keys**, which IE11 **not supporting**. How I'm discovered this? By entering [this site](https://cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/) I'm found that *ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256* is **MISSING**.

This is how it's looks like from my VM:
[image]

So, If I'll be able to add support on this (ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256) cipher, this website will be running good.

### Questions:

1. How to add support on this cipher? Tried to run Windows updates
   without success.
2. No meter which machine I'll fix, this machine is only one of many VM in the cluster. How I can fix this in the whole cluster?
3. Because my server encounter every day new URLs (with potential new ciphers). How I'm can support every possible cipher?

Comment: Don't use ECC.  There are far easier ways to provide the NSA with access to your server.

Comment: It's not my call. My server is a crawler that have to deal with many websites...

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do on those servers? Does it need to be done with IE11? If you're running an application that relies on IE's SSL libs, have you tried adapting your application to use some other, more modern SSL lib?

Comment: I using those machine to run my C# code. My code is enounter the same problem like IE does. So, my goal is to make IE work with those sites, in thinking that this will also solve my C# code problems.